# JavaScript debug breakpoints not working in IntellijIDEA

Tags: javascript, debugging, intellij-idea, vite, javascript-debugger

I have a Rails and React app that I'm debugging in IntelliJIdea 2022.2.3. I'm using Vite and not webpack.

I've set breakpoints on both ends of the app, but only the Ruby breakpoints are hitting.
Both debug servers are running on the same ip and port. 0.0.0.0:3000.

I tried setting the debug server to the same port (3000) but I'm still encountering the same problem.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Got a similar issue with a VueJs project with TS and Webpack, debugger stops randomly in .vue file and not on the breakpoint location.
Got the vue.config devtools set to "source-map"
On the same project working on migration to Vite, works perfectly so not sure what the issue is but assuming it's related to the source map type, just didn't find the one that works from the available options on webpack documentation
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to start the rails server as I normally would (`bundle exec rails s`) before trying to start the JavaScript debugger in Intellij. Now my JavaScript breakpoints are hitting.

---

**31 October update**

I'm encountering the same issue on my work machine my previous fix isn't working.

I noticed in Google's dev tools that, unlike on my personal machine, the javascript dirs are not being loaded.

*Personal machine:*

[image: dir from personal machine]

*work computer*

[image]

I wonder if I built the app on my personal computer at some point but I haven't on my work machine?

---

**Solution**
The discrepancy I noticed between the browsers was related to sourcemaps. I'd forgotten that I added a flag on my local `vite.config.ts` that I did not add on my work station:

```
    build: {
        outDir: 'build',
        sourcemap: true,
    }
```

Comment: this is expected - you have to start the server first and then, when it's up, start the **JavaScript debug** run configuration to attach the debugger to the application running in browser